# Code first migration to Azure database / webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, azure

I'm having trouble setting up Visual Studio and my Web Service hosted on the Azure platform. My webservice needs to connect to an AzureDB.

The troubles begin when i try to Code first migrate my data models into my Azure database. I'm not sure how this is done, because when i try to do it in the Package Manager, it keeps doing it on the local database, and not on the Azure database. The guides i've found seems to be outdated, or not working with VS2019 somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update-package command picks up the connection string from your "startup" project in your solution, which is likely to be your website.

So you *could* update the connection string in there, and if your permissions are correct, you'll be able to deploy to the remote database.

What I would suggest is look into to doing a proper pipelined solution, where the migration runs as part of a deployment to an environment.